# How many non-homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb Q$ are there?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, continuity, set-theory, rational-numbers

How many non-homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb Q$ are there?

$\aleph_1$ ? $\mathfrak c$ ? Is it known?

**EDIT.**

Since the time I originally posted the question I found out about the result in https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08130 (Proposition 19). I haven't studied it yet, but it solves my question, because each countable ordinal is emeddable into $\mathbb Q$.

Now I am leaving the question for 'share knowledge' reasons as there are possibly other ways of proving this (one of them suggested by Eric Wofsey).

Comment: I've taken the odd step of both upvoting **and** voting to close. Here's why: this question as written is not a good fit for this site, since there's no context/work shown/etc. However, the underlying mathematical question is *quite good*; as soon as the question is improved, I'll be the first to vote to re-open (and I'll answer it).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628550/how-many-metrics-are-there-on-a-set-up-to-topological-equivalence/1630421#1630421) I show there are $\mathfrak{c}$ different countable metric spaces up to homeomorphism, and [any countable metric space embeds in $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850645/can-any-at-most-countable-metric-space-be-embedded-topologically-in-mathbbq).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Unfortunately, close votes are usually death sentences for a post. I may humbly suggest that voting to close an interesting question is not effective (or "good", whatever you think that means).

Answer (score 3):

As you observe, every countable ordinal embeds topologically (indeed, order-theoretically) into the rationals. Distinct ordinals can be homeomorphic (e.g. $\omega+1\cong\omega+2$), but distinct ordinals of the form $\omega^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ (= "right-indecomposable") aren't, so this gives us $\aleph_1$ many homeomorphism types. But contra your edit, this leaves open the issue of whether there are as many as possible (= $\mathfrak{c}$-many) in case CH fails.

To get continuum-many, we can use the following trick. First fix a closed $A\subset\mathbb{Q}$ of ordertype $\omega^\omega$; note that $A$ has limit points of every finite order (limit, limit-of-limits, limit-of-limits-of-limits, etc.), and let $\alpha_i$ be an element of $A$ which is an $i$-fold limit but not an $(i+1)$-fold limit for each $i$. For $p\in A$, let $\epsilon_p$ be half the distance between $p$ and the next element of $A$ (which is positive since $A$ is well-ordered).

Given $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, let $$A_X=A\cup\bigcup_{i\in X}([\alpha_i,\alpha_i+\epsilon_{\alpha_i}]\cap\mathbb{Q}).$$ Basically, we attach a "$\mathbb{Q}$-like label" to the $\alpha_i$s which code elements of $X$, and don't attach these labels to the ones that don't. It's a good exercise to show that $A_X\cong A_Y\iff X=Y$, and so we do indeed get continuum-many pairwise-non-homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb{Q}$.